# [ios]how can i set emmiterlayer rendermode?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

Hi i develop core animation for iOS 5 and I want to use CAEmmiterLayer. But I need to set some properties like rendermode. 
I get error that it is unsupported for iOS. But iOS 5 should have support CAEmmiterLayer no?

```
CA_EXTERN NSString * const kCAEmitterLayerPoints
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING (__MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_NA);
```

I find that in library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING (__MAC_10_6, __IPHONE_NA);` means that its not applicable(NA) on any iOS and only available on macosx 10.6+

Comment: I understand it but on wwdc 11 at essential core animation training they said it is supported by ios5

Comment: Witch XCode are you using? 4.0 or 4.2?
btw try to update iOS5 sdk